# Check textbox string and use CSS pseudo class in accordance to string contents

Tags: jquery, css

I have a text box:

```
<input type = "text" name = "promo" class = "promobox" id = "promobox" placeholder= "PROMO CODE" />
```

I want to check to see if the contents of that checkbox are my promo code "student", if not, then I'll use a pseudo class, say, `#promobox:badCode{}`, if it matches, then I'll use say `#promobox:goodCode{}`

This is what I currently have inside of my script tags:

```
$('promobox').keyup(onchange() {
    if ($("#promobox").val() != "student") {
        $(this).addClass("badCode");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("goodCode");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several syntax problems . You are missing a `#` in first selector and `onchange` should be `function`.

Also need to remove the opposite class when transition between good/bad

Try:

```
$('#promobox').keyup(function(){
   var $this= $(this); // cache $(this);

    if( $this.val() != "student"){
        $this.addClass("badCode").removeClass('goodcode');
    }else{
        $this.addClass("goodCode").removeClass('badcode');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, that still doesn't seem to work. I'm using #promobox:goodCode and #promobox:badCode in the CSS. Thanks

Comment: those aren't pseudo classes, they are proper classes so should use dot in css Check the live html in dev tools console html inspector, can see exactly what class is applied

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Still no dice for some reason. I at least understand the concept though. Thank you.

Comment: don't just go by css visuals, it's posisble you have other more specific rules at play ... use dev tools inspector to find out both the class in html and the specific rules that are at play

Comment: So as I enter text into the box, I should see the style or CSS element used on the box change?

Comment: ideally yes ..depending on what the default rules are though and that your new rules are specific enough to override defaults

Comment: and also ALWAYS check browser console for errors thrown. That's your first line of debugging